# I am trying to save frames from a webcam via Python and ffmpeg, but the video becomes way to fast

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I get a stream of `cv2` images from my webcam and want to save it to a video file. After playing a bit with `cv2.VideoWriter()` it turned out that using `ffmpeg` would provide more options and - apparently, following a few threads here on SO - lead to better results. So I gave the [VidGear Python library](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/writegear/compression/overview/) a try, and it seems to work fine.

There is one catch though: My webcam provides a variable framerate, most of the time between 10 and 30 FPS. When saving these frames the video file becomes way too fast, like watching in fast-forward. One real-time minute becomes only a few seconds in the video.

I tried to play with various combinations of the ffmpeg's `-framerate` and/or `-r` parameters, but without luck. Here is the command I am using right now:

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt bgra -framerate 25.0 -i - -vcodec libx265 -crf 25 -r 25 -preset fast <output_video_file>
```

For the records, I am creating the `WriteGear` class from the VidGear library like this:

```py
video_params = {
    "-vcodec": "libx265",
    "-crf": 25,
    "-input_framerate": 25,
    "-r": 25,
}
WriteGear(output_filename=video_file, logging=True, **video_params)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here and how I need to call ffmpeg?

Comment: Try `-vsync vfr` instead of `-r`

Comment: please clarify: do you use opencv, or do you use vidgear?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I get images from my webcam as `numpy` arrays, thus via OpenCV. I want to put all these images into a video, using VidGear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my issue now by using `cv2.VideoWriter()` instead of the VidGear library. Don't know why, but I was not able to get the latter working in a proper way - either it was me not using it correctly, or the library is broken (for my use case).

Either way, after playing around with the OpenCV solution, it turned out that using the `VideoWriter` class and providing the FPS value from the web cam everything works quite well now.

For the records, one thing to note though: Even after finding a correct codec for my platform and double-checking the dimensions of the images to be saved, I still ended up with an "empty" (1k) .mp4 video file. The reason was that all frames from my webcam came with 4 channels, but the `VideoWriter` class apparently expects frames with 3 channels instead, silently dropping all other, "invalid" frames. With the following code I was able to convert my 4-channel images:

```
if len(image.shape) > 2 and image.shape[2] == 4:
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
```